# value of options loaded from db in dropdown list

Tags: php, html, database, fetch

I used the below code to get the datas or options in my dropdown list from mysql db. also it works fine, but my problem is when i select a particular option from this dropdown list, on submission no value or empty value is saving for that for field. simply i can see the option name, but value is seems like this

> value=" ";

actually, value is what i see  as option name.

```
<strong> Select Data </strong> 
<select name="data1"> 
    <option value=""> NONE </option> 
    <?php
//Mysql db connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

    //Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

//Perform queries 
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT relation FROM relation_names");
    if ($rs && mysqli_num_rows($rs)) {
        while ($rd = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {
            echo("<option value='$rd->id'>$rd->relation</option>");
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: just add id to your query and it should work as expected. `SELECT DISTINCT relation,id FROM relation_names`.

Comment: vote to close as typo

Comment: @Faisal TA Add `id` to your `SELECT` statement and that should work fine in your case. I'm sure you are also aware adding `*` will pick all the columns in the mySQL table as well.

Comment: that works fine, but now  i get id as values, but i need what i seen as option as values, not the id.

Comment: got it and thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `id` in query too

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT relation,id FROM relation_names");
```

Then only

```
$rd->id
```

will populate correct value

***If you want relation as value then do like below:***

```
echo("<option value='$rd->relation'>$rd->relation</option>");
```

Comment: that works fine, but now i get id as values, but i need what i seen as option as values, not the id.